# Wordpress 3.6: Mediaelement (audio) hide elements

Tags: css, wordpress

With the mediaelement.js wordpress now has a native audio/video player. The problem is the customization and I don't want to change the core mediaelement.css.

The standard theme looks somewhat like [this](http://brianshim.com/webtricks/style-the-wordpress-3-6-media-player/).

This page already shows how to modify some settings. I changed those a little..

```
.mejs-time-rail, 
.mejs-time-total,
.mejs-currenttime,
.mejs-duration, 
.mejs-volume-button, 
.mejs-horizontal-volume-slider,
{
    display: none !important;
}

.mejs-container {
    width: 26px !important;
}
```

..to hide everything except the play and pause button. Additionally I tried to add some short text right/left to the player which is atm not shown.

```
[audio mp3="audio_path"]I am a very important message[/audio]
```

**The code above hides all controls except the play button, shrinks the width but the text is not visible. Any ideas what to do?**

Answer (score 0):

To hide everything except the play and pause button try:

**CSS**

```
.mejs-time,
.mejs-time-rail,
.mejs-volume-button,
.mejs-mute,
.mejs-horizontal-volume-slider {
    display: none !important;
}
.mejs-container {
    width: 26px !important;
}
```

Because of `26px` maybe text is not shown properly. Move it outside maybe useful in your case.

```
[audio mp3="audio_path"][/audio] I am a very important message
```

Comment: well that pretty much has the same effect as the original code but the text is still not visible :?

Comment: @Duboe Why you not move text outside the audio tag?

Comment: well yeah I tested that the problem atm is that the player width is somehow still at 100% and the text is moved to the line below. inside was just a test :/